# how to define a view of 3 tables in a datasource file (. xml)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I want to define a view of 3 tables in a datasource
file, but I do not know the exact syntax! Could you help me please? 
PS: I do not know if I used the correct syntax. In fact I do not even know if we should gather the 3 tables in the same or separate tag! 
Thank you for your help,
  here is my code:

```
<DataSource 
    dbName="SQLServer_CRM"
    tableName="crm_objects"
    ID="crm_objects"
    dataSourceVersion="1"
    generatedBy="v8.3p"
    serverType="sql"
>
    <!--
    Based on : the real table
    Used by  : CRM > CRM Object
    -->
    <fields>
        <field name="crm_obj_idnum"                 title="Obj ID Num"          type="sequence"     hidden="false" primaryKey="true" />
        <field name="crm_obj_parent_idnum"          title="Parent ID"           type="integer"      foreignKey="crm_objects.crm_obj_idnum" rootValue="1" detail="true" required="true" canSave="true" canEdit="false"  hidden="true"/>
        <field name="crm_obj_name"                  title="Name"                type="ntext"        length="150"    required="true"></field>

        <!-- Manage the Kind -->
        <field name="crm_obj_kind"                  title="Kind"                type="integer"      foreignKey="crm_kind.crm_kind_idnum" displayField="crm_kind_name" canSave="true" canEdit="false" required="true"/>
        <field name="crm_kind_name"                 includeFrom="crm_kind.crm_kind_name" hidden="true"/>
        <field name="crm_kind_icon"                 includeFrom="crm_kind.crm_kind_icon" hidden="true"/>

        <field name="crm_obj_desc"                  title="Description"         type="ntext"        length="500"></field>
        <field name="crm_obj_isactive"              title="isActive ?"          type="boolean"      sqlStorageStrategy="integer"  />

        <field name="crm_obj_background"            title="Background"          type="ntext"        length="7"></field>
        <field name="crm_obj_forecolor"             title="Color"               type="ntext"        length="7"></field>

        <field name="crm_obj_dact"                  title="Action"              type="datetime"     canSave="false" canEdit="false" />
        <field name="crm_obj_dnac"                  title="Next Action"         type="datetime"     canSave="false" canEdit="false" />
        <field name="crm_obj_dcre"                  title="Created"             type="datetime"     canSave="false" canEdit="false" />
        <field name="crm_obj_dupd"                  title="Updated"             type="datetime"     canSave="false" canEdit="false" />
        <!-- Manage the data -->
         <field name="crm_attrdat_data_A1"          includeFrom="crm_attrdata.crm_attrdat_data_A1" hidden="true"/> 
    </fields>

    <operationBindings>

        <operationBinding operationType="fetch">
            <tableClause>crm_objects,crm_kind, crm_attrdata</tableClause>
            <whereClause>crm_objects.crm_obj_kind = crm_kind.crm_kind_idnum AND crm_objects.crm_obj_idnum = crm_attrdata.crm_attrdat_fk_obj_idnum AND ($defaultWhereClause)</whereClause>
        </operationBinding>
    </operationBindings>

    <!-- <operationBindings>    
         <operationBinding operationType="fetch">
            <tableClause>crm_objects,crm_attrdata</tableClause>
            <whereClause>crm_objects.crm_obj_idnum = crm_attrdata.crm_attrdat_fk_obj_idnum AND ($defaultWhereClause)</whereClause> 
        </operationBinding>

    </operationBindings> -->
</DataSource>
```

Comment: We are not in english literature class bknopper !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution :

```
<DataSource 
    dbName="SQLServer_CRM"

    ID="crm_view_object_data"
    dataSourceVersion="1"
    generatedBy="v8.3p"
    serverType="sql"
>
    <!--
    Based on : A view
    Used by  : CRM > 
    -->
      <fields>
        <field name="OBJ_ID"                        title="Obj ID Num"          type="sequence"     hidden="true"   canSave="false"  canEdit="false" primaryKey="true" />
        <field name="OBJ_KIND"                      title="OBJ_KIND"            type="integer"      hidden="true"   canSave="false"  canEdit="false"/>
        <field name="OBJ_KIND_NAME"                 title="OBJ_KIND_NAME"       type="ntext"        hidden="true"   canSave="true"  canEdit="true"/>
        <field name="OBJ_KIND_ICON"                 title="OBJ_KIND_ICON"       type="ntext"        hidden="true"   canSave="false"  canEdit="false"/>
        <field name="FATHER_NAME"                   title="FATHER_NAME"         type="ntext"        hidden="true"   canSave="true"  canEdit="true"/>
        <field name="FATHER_ID"                     title="FATHER_ID"           type="integer"      hidden="true"   canSave="false"  canEdit="false"/>
        <field name="OBJ_NAME"                      title="OBJ_NAME"            type="ntext"        hidden="true"   canSave="true"  canEdit="true"/>
        <field name="OBJ_DESC"                      title="OBJ_DESC"            type="ntext"        hidden="true"   canSave="true"  canEdit="true"/>
        <field name="OBJ_ACTIVE"                    title="OBJ_ACTIVE"          type="boolean"      sqlStorageStrategy="integer" hidden="true" canSave="true" canEdit="true"  />


    </fields> 


      <operationBindings>
        <operationBinding operationType="fetch">
             <customSQL>
            SELECT  OBJ_DET.crm_obj_idnum                   AS OBJ_ID
              ,OBJ_DET.crm_obj_kind                         AS OBJ_KIND
              ,OBJ_KN.crm_kind_name                         AS OBJ_KIND_NAME      
              ,OBJ_KN.crm_kind_icon                         AS OBJ_KIND_ICON      
              ,OBJ_FATHER.crm_obj_name                      AS FATHER_NAME
              ,OBJ_DET.crm_obj_parent_idnum                 AS FATHER_ID
              ,OBJ_DET.crm_obj_name                         AS OBJ_NAME
              ,OBJ_DET.crm_obj_desc                         AS OBJ_DESC
              ,OBJ_DET.crm_obj_isactive                     AS OBJ_ACTIVE
            FROM 
            crm_objects OBJ_DET,
            crm_objects OBJ_FATHER,
            crm_kind OBJ_KN
            WHERE OBJ_DET.crm_obj_parent_idnum=OBJ_FATHER.crm_obj_idnum AND OBJ_DET.crm_obj_kind = OBJ_KN.crm_kind_idnum
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                  crm_attrdat_fk_obj_idnum                      AS OBJ_ID
                  ,OBJ_FATHER_DATA.crm_obj_kind                 AS OBJ_KIND
                  ,OBJ_KN.crm_kind_name                         AS OBJ_KIND_NAME
                  ,OBJ_KN.crm_kind_icon                         AS OBJ_KIND_ICON
                  ,OBJ_FATHER_DATA.crm_obj_name                 AS FATHER_NAME
                  ,crm_attrdat_fk_obj_idnum                     AS FATHER_ID
                  ,case OBJ_ATTR_DATA.crm_attr_datatype WHEN 'A' THEN crm_attrdat_data_A1 END AS OBJ_NAME
                  ,OBJ_ATTR_DATA.crm_attr_name                  AS OBJ_DESC
                  ,crm_attrdat_isactive                         AS OBJ_ACTIVE
            FROM 
            crm_attrdata OBJ_DATA,
            crm_attributs OBJ_ATTR_DATA,
            crm_objects OBJ_FATHER_DATA,
            crm_kind OBJ_KN
            WHERE OBJ_DATA.crm_attrdat_fk_attr_idnum=OBJ_ATTR_DATA.crm_attr_idnum
            AND OBJ_DATA.crm_attrdat_fk_obj_idnum=OBJ_FATHER_DATA.crm_obj_idnum
            AND OBJ_ATTR_DATA.crm_attr_fk_kind_idnum = OBJ_KN.crm_kind_idnum
           </customSQL>
        </operationBinding>
    </operationBindings>  


</DataSource>
```